# If-else statement always run the else statement in login.php

Tags: php

I am creating a login page using php and mysqli, however, when i type the wrong user name and password, it cannot not show the error message.

```
<?php

session_start();
$error="";
//connect database
include("../task2/db_setting.php");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

    //email and password from form
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    $password= md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']));

    //Retrive data from database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' and password = '$password'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION["login_user"]=$row[email];
        $_SESSION["id"]=$row[id];
        }
    }
    else {
        $error="Your Login name or password is invalid";
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION["login_user"]))
        header("location:account.php");
}?>
```

If i type a wrong username, its only cannot log in but the $error didn't appear, i tried to change it to echo but turn up, it will always echo the error message before i log in or type anythings. I think this implies the code always run the else statement.

Anyone know what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Mixing OO and functional mysqli, okaaaay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(isset($error))
    {
    echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:12px;">'.$error.'</div>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Add this Line Where You Want Display Error Message

Comment: May i know what is the theory behind this? And why my original code cannot work?

Comment: :) Yupp Happy To Help ... Any Time :)

Comment: Actually , You Just Define The Error Variable and Pass the Message , Its Not Print Any Where , So there For We Just Check that error Variable is isset then just echo the $error !!!

Answer (score -1):

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);

if($row['password']==md5($upass))

{

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $row['id']; 

header("Location: account.php");
```

}

else

{

?>

```
    <script>alert('You Entered Wrong Details');</script>

    <?php
```

}